# Disable Drupal content creation message?

Tags: drupal

Whenever a content item is created, a message is displayed like this:

```
[Content Type] [Name] has been created.
```

Is there any way to disable this message for specific users? Or for all users would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`node_form_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form_submit/6) that is creating those messages. You could pretty easily use hook_form_alter on the node form and use your own version of `node_form_submit` instead. All you would need to do, would be to copy the function and add an `user_access('whatever')` check before that message is created.

Alternatively, you could in preprocess_page function, check which messages is being served, and remove unwanted ones, but that would be a bit more tricky. Should be possible with some regex. On the other hand, this method would be a bit more upgrade friendly, since you could remain using the `node_form_submit` function and would get future changes if any.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best practice would be to use `hook_nodeapi()` and `drupal_get_messages('status')`. The `$op` for `hook_nodeapi()` would be `insert`. Ex:

```
mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
  if ($node->type == 'content_type_to_check_for' && $op == 'insert') {
    drupal_get_messages('status');
  }
}
```

Comment: i naively thought it could be changed at preprocess_page, but template_preprocess_page already processed it by then.

Comment: Yet at least in drupal 6, the insert hook is fired when node_form_submit calls node_save, before the messages are set.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way I discovered to hide such messages for specific content types (the node type is 'request'):

```
// specific node type form alteration hook (implements [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter][1]())
function MYCUSTOMMODULE_form_request_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // ... 
  // custom validation function
  $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_request_node_form_validate';
  // ...
}
function _custom_request_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  //...
  // here we can set a submit handler that is executed before 
  // node_form_submit which sets the messages we are trying to hide
  $form_state['submit_handlers'][] = '_custom_request_node_disable_msg';
  //...
}
function _custom_request_node_disable_msg($form, &$form_state) {
  //...
  // clear status messages
  drupal_get_messages('status');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be to user [Disable Messages](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module.
There are many kind of messages that can be disabled by this module:

- Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
- Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
- Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
- Disable all filtering for specific users.
- Disable all filtering for specific paths.
- Apply filtering only for specific paths.
- Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Rules module, then you can use the new module I created called ["Better Rules Message"](http://drupal.org/node/409090#comment-2922678).
By using this you can setup a rule that will delete all of the messages after a node is being created...

Hopefully this will be added to the main Rules module in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

googletorp is right (about the submit function). But unfortunately you can't decouple the message from the node submit function and duplicating the functionality (without the message) is going to mean your site might break when a security release is issued. You'd have to maintain your own version of that function. It's probably not a big deal but it's a good idea to follow best practice.

You'll need to write your own submit hook either before or after node_form_submit gets called.

With a submit hook after the node save, you could remove the message from `$_SESSION['messages']` if the messages array was easy enough to work with. I imagine that would be simple enough. See [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_message/6)

OR

You could write some class in CSS in your body tag and set the display to none when status messages are returned on the page that the node form submits to. But that might put your business logic in your theme layer which should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stringoverrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module in drupal ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following module to disable specific messages in Drupal - http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages